# Create AWS EC2 Windows instance using encrypted EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am trying to create an EC2 instance (running Windows Server 2012 R2) with an encrypted EBS volume. I am using OpsWorks and there doesn't seem to be an option to create an EC2 instance with an encrypted volume. I am wondering if there is a way to do this **without** going through the process of creating a blank, encrypted volume, attaching it to the instance, and then copying everything over to the encrypted volume. I would prefer to not have to do that as it does not seem like a simple process.

Comment: Do you want the encrypted volume to be the boot volume, or a secondary volume? Officially, Amazon EC2 cannot use an encrypted boot volume (but there are workarounds).

Comment: I would like it to be the boot volume if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Elastic Blocks Store (EBS) does not currently offer encryption for boot volumes.

From the [EBS Encryption documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html):

> Encrypted boot volumes are not supported at this time.

So, it's not related specifically to OpsWorks, it applies to EBS as a whole.

This is possibly because snapshots would also be encrypted, so it would not be possible to create an AMI (since it uses a snapshot and would therefore be encrypted, too).

It is theoretically possible to create an encrypted boot volume by creating a blank encrypted volume, copying all the contents to the new volume and then attaching it as a boot volume. However, this would disallow use of an AMI.

Comment: For posterity's sake this no longer seems to be the case. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-encrypted-ebs-boot-volumes/